# Any resource where all the Google webfonts are listed?

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts

until Google launched the new Google Webfonts directory I used to read all the fonts dynamically vie PHP regex and output them in forms to have the possibility to use any Google Webfont as soon as it is available without adding it manually to a list. Now, this is not possible any more.
Does anyone know a feed or an other "static" resource from which we still could get the fonts automatically?

Best regards, .wired

Comment: Yep, just brought it to 50% ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the googlefontdirectory's Google Code page, the source is available via mercurial.

- http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/browse/

Comment: Hmm, but I rather thought of a solution I can use with PHP, no command line tools (as for example, this code for PHP would be perfect to use for themes).